# Median of trapezoid with perpendicular diagonals

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

In a trapezoid, the diagonals have lengths $10$ and $24$, and are perpendicular to each other. Find the length of the median?

Comment: Yes, what did thou try?

Comment: what do you mean with median?

Comment: And what is the median of a trapezium?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel The median is the segment that joins the midpoints of the non-parallel lines.

Comment: I think to know the proposer of this problem (*Olimpiadi della Matematica*, February 2016)...

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Take $a$ and $b$ to be the lengths of the segments of the length-10 and length-24 diagonals respectively that are on one side of the intersection point, as shown. By similarity of triangles we have
$$\frac ab=\frac{10-a}{24-b}$$
$$(24-b)a=b(10-a)$$
$$24a=10b\qquad12a=5b$$
Without loss of generality we may take $a=5$ and $b=12$. Then the trapezium is a rhombus and its median length is the same as its side length – $\sqrt{5^2+12^2}=13$. The sum of the parallel sides' lengths remains the same (26) regardless of how the two diagonals are positioned, so the median length stays constant as well.

Answer (score 0):

Say $ABCD$ is the trapezoid $AB||CD$. Draw a parallel to $BD$ through $C$ which cuts line $AB$ at $E$. Then $$AE = \sqrt{10^2+24^2} =26$$ But it is easy to see that middle line of the triangle $AEC$ (parallel to $AE$) has the same length as the middle line od trapezoid $ABCD$ and thus it is $13$.